# I2C bus pollutes power rail

Tags: noise, i2c, ripple, power-integrity

Working on a new revision of a design with a new I2C LED driver connected to
SAM S70 Cortex-M7,  I noticed some high speed ripple on 5V rail when using a 1Ghz scope.
The PCB has 2 I2C buses and both of them pollute 3V3 and 5V rails respectively. However, the p-p ripple on 5V is higher.

[image]

[image]

The I2C bus for the LED driver is pulled up to 3V3, the LED driver sits on 5V rail. The termination resistors are placed close to the MCU. MCU configures the pins to open drain when TWI is used.

The only thing I could do to reduce the ripple is to try different combinations of termination and pull-up resistor values, plus put filtering caps. The best combination so far is 220 Ohms termination resistors and 5.1K pull-ups. Interesting thing is that SDA line causes the highest ripple when it reaches 0V (controlled by the MCU).
This is actually a TWI bus, so there is no slew control for this interface.

Is the anything I can do to minimize this ripple?

Comment: I’d look carefully at how your probing the signal. You shouldn’t be seeing those glitches. Make sure the probe is earthed to a solid gnd on the pcb , preferably as short as possible. High speed scopes are great, but they can show you ghosts if you’re not careful.

Comment: I suspect it is not really there - try touching the scope probe to ground clip with the scope ground clip in the normal place. The scope trace should be completely clean. I have never heard of IC2 lines interfering with anything.

Comment: Are you using PCB that you designed yourself? Did you ground and decouple with EMC in mind? Although it's very likely that fellow commenters are right in this being some issue with the measurement, it would be good to keep in mind (edit: just saw the voltage scale, yeah that doesn't seem right)

Comment: Well, the spikes were first discovered without SDA and SCL probed. The frequency of the ripple pointed out to the I2C bus. That's why I hesitant to suspect the incorrect probing. My question should sound more like: has anyone else saw this phenomenon?

Comment: Please share your schematic. For example, termination resistors aren't typically used in I2C. So where did you connect them? At the master? At the slaves? What value capacitors did you use and where did you place them? Etc.

Comment: The waveforms make no sense. Please post schematics and code. Are the MCU I2C pins push-pull or open-drain?

Comment: Schematics added

Comment: With the 200 ohm series resistance on the source limiting drive current, it is unlikely you have much noise from the I2C lines themselves.  Is there some decoupling on that MCU and LED driver IC that isn't included on the schematic?  If not, you may get some nasty noise on the power rails whenever the MCU/LED driver respond to or generate I2C traffic.

Comment: Its just a sketch. MCU has more than enough decoupling and bulk capacitance on 3.3V rail. The LED driver is tested on a breakout board with 100nF+10uF.